# Android Unit Tests with proguard enabled

Tags: android, unit-testing, proguard

I have a problem that Proguard strips out methods of my debug APK (I need to run proguard on debug beccause of method dex file limit), even if they are used in the Test apk. E.g. i use GSON addProeprty method in Unit test, but not in the App apk.  This method gets stripped away and causes the test to fail. But i do not want to configure proguard to just keep all of GSOn because of the dex file limit, but also do not want to list all methods seperately. is there a way to tell rpguard to consider the unit tests as source code entry points?

Comment: None of the answers as of Sept 2023 solves the root problem: Proguard does not consider unit tests as source code entry points. This is really a major issue for anyone who wants to unit/UI test production code, i.e. minified code. Dropping minification is a workaround. Explicitly excluding files from minifcation is a workaround and one that requires constant maintenance.

Answer (score 45):

This is what I did.

Add a custom proguard rules file.

**/project/app/proguard-test-rules.pro**

```
# Proguard rules that are applied to your test apk/code.
-ignorewarnings

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontnote junit.framework.**
-dontnote junit.runner.**

-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn android.support.test.**
-dontwarn org.junit.**
-dontwarn org.hamcrest.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.javawriter.JavaWriter
# Uncomment this if you use Mockito
#-dontwarn org.mockito.**
```

The add the following to your build.gradle for your app. To use the proguard file when testing.

**/project/app/build.gradle**

```
android {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        testProguardFile 'proguard-test-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: you sir, are awesome!

Comment: I missed the "test" in testProguardFile the first time I tried this solution, thanks!

Comment: tried with android library. no luck. The aar is obfuscated, but test apk is not obfuscated.

Comment: Check [google sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/app/proguard-test-rules.pro) from which that file was shared.

Answer (score 7):

None of the above answers did the trick for me.  I had two issues: I needed to also use the default proguard file for testing, and my default proguard file was wrong.

1. To use the default proguard file, in addition to your own:

   ```
   android {
       debug {
           minifyEnabled true
           testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project-test.pro'
       }
   }
   ```
2. The default proguard file (and all of the `tools/proguard` folder) is apparently [not replaced by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212749/proguard-failing-with-25-1-6-release-of-android-tools) when you update the SDK tools through Android studio.  My machine was using an outdated config file, which was causing weird proguard issues.  To update proguard's default config, replace ~/Library/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt with [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android.txt).

Comment: Was just going through addressing the second issue. I think it's worth mentioning that as of version 2.2.0 of the android plugin for gradle, `proguard-android.txt` is no longer used and instead the default rules are generated at build time. Source: [Android plugin for Gradle, revision 2.2.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html)

Answer (score 4):

Instrumentation tests (and others?) do not use the same proguard file as your debug/release apk's.  You might try setting the `testProguardFile` option inside the debug and release blocks.  This test-specific proguard file can be very permissive because it's not being used for the debug/release apk's.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem in my build by having an additional "dev" `buildType` where I enable proguard, but configure it to keep all code in my own package, and a few specific library classes that happen to be used from tests only. I also disable obfuscation in the dev `buildType` so that it can be debugged from an IDE.

For debug and release builds I use my "real" proguard settings including obfuscation and optimizations.

Comment: can you share a similar proguard file ?

Comment: Thank you, that should work. However, we have several flavors and module and having another build type for all of them is kind of a mess. Custom proguard rules from the other answer helped.