# Proguard failing with 25.1.6 release of Android tools

Tags: android, proguard, android-sdk-tools

I downloaded the 25.1.6 release of Android tools today and I'm noticing that proguard is falling over with this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug'.
> /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt line 43:15 extraneous input '[]' expecting ')'
```

I'm certain that I've not changed anything in the `proguard-android.txt` file. Line 43 reads for me as follows:

```
void set*(%[]);
```

I'm noticing that the file here...

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/android-6.0.1_r43/files/proguard-android.txt

... is different to what I have on my machine? Is that file the latest version of the file that I should have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, it looks the `tools/proguard` folder in my local copy of the Android SDK is not updated by the Android SDK Manager. I just downloaded the Android SDK afresh from here...

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

... and replaced the `tools/proguard` folder in that distribution over the `tools/proguard` in my local copy of the Android SDK and the error's gone.

Would be great if the `tools/proguard` folder was updated via the Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 4):

Just to know several options:

The thing that helped me is replacing corresponding `proguard-android.txt` file with the one from [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/sdk/+/master/files/proguard-android.txt) page

And just in case the page goes away saving its content here:

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

Comment: Where to find "corresponding proguard-android.txt file"?

Comment: I have found mine in `~/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt`. If this would not work for you, try `find /path/to/android/sdk | grep 'proguard-android.txt'`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that's happening to some of us. I downloaded just the folder attached in this answer and copied it to android-sdk/tools folder overwriting what's there and now it works without problems.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210012

Comment: Hi @Eylen, please see my answer in this thread. The root problem I found is that the `tools/proguard` folder is not updated as part of the Android tools update in the Android SDK Manager window. You're probably best getting the `tools/proguard` folder from a fresh download of the Android SDK rather than the link in your answer because it's likely the latter will not be updated and will become dated with time.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. But I hope that in future updates the folder will update correctly

Answer (score 0):

In debug mode I set *minifyEnabled* to *false*

Comment: You'll run into this problem then when you do a release build... unless the files in your `<Android SDK>/tools/proguard` folder are up to date.